# ImportError from Cython when linking an external C library

Tags: python, c, cython, gsl

I am trying to replicate the work of Flavian Coelho, [linked here](http://pyinsci.blogspot.com/2010/12/efficcient-mcmc-in-python.html). He used Cython and the Gnu Scientific Library (GSL) to get a huge speed-up over Python in generating random numbers. When I import my compiled Cython code in Python (with the command `import cgibbs`), I get the following error:

```
  ImportError: dlopen(./cgibbs.so, 2): Symbol not found: _gsl_rng_mt19937
  Referenced from: /Users/wesley/scratch/cython/cgibbs.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

You'll notice that the complaint is that the symbol `_gsl_rng_mt19937` can't be found. The function i am trying to link to is called `gsl_rng_mt19937` (no leading underscore), and that is how it appears in my `.pyx` file. I think Cython is somehow causing the problem by adding that leading underscore.

In order to make troubleshooting easier, I've stripped the code down and posted it below. My system is: Mac OSX 10.7 (Lion) running Python 2.7.2 (32-bit), gcc-4.0 (which I used to compile the GSL libraries in 32-bit form), GSL 1.15, and Cython v0.15.1.

Here is the content of cgibbs.pyx:

```
#declaring external GSL functions to be used
cdef extern from "math.h":
   double sqrt(double)

cdef double Sqrt(double n):
   return sqrt(n)

cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_rng.h":
   ctypedef struct gsl_rng_type:
       pass
   ctypedef struct gsl_rng:
       pass
   gsl_rng_type *gsl_rng_mt19937
   gsl_rng *gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_type * T)

cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_randist.h":
   double gamma "gsl_ran_gamma"(gsl_rng * r,double,double)
   double gaussian "gsl_ran_gaussian"(gsl_rng * r,double)


cdef gsl_rng *r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937)
```

The error goes away if I comment out the last line of my `cgibbs.pyx`, but then I can't actually use the external library... Any insight you can offer is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @ChuiTey, I discovered that `otool` and `nm` are the tools on the Mac that can do what objdump does on Linux. With `nm` I found that the leading underscores are part of the symbol name in the `libgsl.a` library.

Once I knew that the linker (in my case, `ld`) was looking for the right name, it was clear that it just wasn't looking in the right place. And that's how I learned that header files don't know the location of the libraries to which they link (Duh!) I just needed to add the option `-lgsl` to the command that runs the linker (this requires that `libgsl.a` is in the directory where your linker looks for libraries - on my machine, that's `/usr/local/lib`.)

I also had to move `libgsl.dylib` from `/usr/local/lib` because it was compiled for a 64-bit  platform and I am using 32-bit Python.

There must be an easy way to specify the `-lgsl` linker option when compiling Cython code with distutils or a makefile; for now I am just running gcc-4.0 twice to compile and then link the module. My workflow to compile a Cython module from the bash command line is:

```
cython cgibbs.pyx
gcc-4.0 -m32 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c cgibbs.c -o cgibbs.o
gcc-4.0 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -lgsl -arch i386 -g cgibbs.o -o cgibbs.so
```

Which produces `cgibbs.so`, a Cython module that can be imported in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

Prepending an underscore to exported functions is known as [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). On Windows, the cdecl convention appends a single underscore (other conventions have more complicated schemes).

It might be that you haven't specified the calling convention correctly when building your GSL library. You should be able to have a look at what names are exported using [objdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_objdump.htm).

Doesn't GSL already provide SWIG wrappers?

Comment: I don't know from SWIG - maybe I ought to, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at CythonGSL (https://github.com/twiecki/CythonGSL) when you want to use GSL functions in Cython.